# LINQtoSQL LEFT JOIN on 1 to 1 relation, method-based

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

Say I have 2 table on 1 to 1 or 0 relation like so:

```
Invoice: ID, Date, OrderID
Order:   ID, Date, Notes (string)
```

as far as the LINQtoSQL i have the INNER JOIN as:

```
customer
.invoices
.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
.Join(context.Orders,
    invoice => invoice.OrderID,
    order => order.OrderID,
    (invoice, order) => new
    {
        invoice = invoice,
        OrderNotes = order.Notes
    })
.ToList()
```

All values that are excluded in the inner join is `WHERE Invoice.OrderID NOT IN (SELECT OrderID FROM Order)`, I have not checked what happens `WHERE Invoice.OrderID IS NULL`

the query that is desired is:

```
SELECT i.*, o.Notes AS OrderNotes 
FROM 
    Invoice AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Order AS o
ON i.OrderID = o.OrderID
```

i understand that the fk's should be switched around, but i don't have the power to change the structure of the DB.

I don't know how to produce LEFT OUTER JOIN effect. looking around I only found solutions for 1 to many LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to all the suggestions I have figured it out how to do it in method-based syntax.

```
customer
.invoices
.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date)
.GroupJoin(context.Orders,
    invoice => invoice.OrderID,
    order => order.OrderID,
    (invoice, orders) => new
    {
        invoice = invoice,
        OrderNotes = orders.SingleOrDefault()==null?"":orders.SingleOrDefault().Notes
    })
.ToList()
```

the key is GroupJoin even though it looks like 1 to many relationship JOIN it works out the way the SQL

Answer (score 1):

Excellent example at msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

should be something like this

```
from i in invoice
join o in order on i.OrderID = o.OrderID into result
from r in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {i.Id, i.someProperty , Notes = (r== null ? String.Empty : r.Notes) };
```

Comment: I am not sure, I understood you correctly. What do you mean by method based ..?

Comment: I mean the `invoices.Select( q => new { q.Something, q.Something1 })` rather than `from q in invoice select new { q.Something, q.Something1 }` syntax.
PS Where are you from? Mongolia? India? I'm curious to know what your name means, because I'm from Mongolia we have Anands here too.

Comment: @fuximusfoe : Oh the lambda expression syntax you were talking about!
I am from India. My name means "Happiness" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = from invoice in context.Invoices
                    join order in context.Orders on new { invoice.OrderId } equals new { order.Id } into groupedJoin
                    from grOrder in groupedJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { Invoice = invoice, Order = grOrder };
```